# How to write such a SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

**There is a table called `user` which structure is like so:**

```
id | ... | qq_unionid | wx_unionid

1  | ... | nfdufdflfl | fdfgnugdgdll

2  | ... | NULL       | dfdfjjdfjd

3  | ... | fdfnfdfull | NULL 

4  | ... | NULL       | NULL
```

**Now, what i want to do is move the two fields `qq_unionid` and `wx_unionid` into another table `thirdpartyinfo` whick looks like so:**

```
id | user_id | qq_nickname | wx_nickname

1  | 1       | Petter      | Petter

2  | 2       | null        | Gorgine

3  | 3       | Julia       | NULL
```

**and what i expected is like below:**

```
id | user_id | qq_unionid | wx_unionid | qq_nickname | wx_nickname

1  | 1       | dfdfdj     |  fdjfkjdd  | Petter      | Petter

2  | 2       | NULL       |  fdjkfjd   | NULL        | Gorgine

3  | 3       | dfdfdfdff  |  NULL      | Julia       | NULL
```

I do not know how to write SQL statement to move the two fields into new table. Please give me a hand. Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you explain, why are you want to move those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `SELECT` the information without moving the columns to the other table. You can also use this query to [create a view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html).

```
SELECT t.id, t.user_id, u.qq_unionid, u.wx_unionid, t.qq_nickname, t.wx_nickname
FROM thirdpartyinfo t INNER JOIN `user` u ON t.user_id = u.id
```

In case you want to create new columns on table `thirdpartyinfo` and set the values from `user` into the new columns you can do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE thirdpartyinfo ADD COLUMN qq_unionid VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  ADD COLUMN wx_unionid VARCHAR(255) NULL
```

The two columns are available now in the `thirdpartyinfo` table. Make sure you are using the correct / needed column definition. After that you can set the values from `user` table to the new columns, using `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE thirdpartyinfo INNER JOIN `user` ON thirdpartyinfo.user_id = `user`.id 
  SET thirdpartyinfo.qq_unionid = `user`.qq_unionid,
      thirdpartyinfo.wx_unionid = `user`.wx_unionid
```

Comment: It helps, and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to make `thirdpartyinfo` table having 2 new fields (i.e. qq_unionid, wx_unionid) and fill these 2 fields with data from `user` table.

First of all, you need to create those 2 new columns in the `thirdpartyinfo` table:

`ALTER TABLE thirdpartyinfo ADD qq_unionid varchar(40) NULL, ADD wx_unionid varchar(40) NULL`

Next you can use `MERGE` to fill in the data from `user` table:

```
MERGE INTO thirdpartyinfo target 
USING (SELECT u.id, u.qq_unionid, u.wx_unionid FROM user u) source
ON (target.id=source.id) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE 
    SET target.qq_unionid = source.qq_unionid, 
        target.wx_unionid = source.wx_unionid;
```

Comment: Yep. Thanks for your help.